# Swift service layer giving api_key to all requests by default

Tags: swift, service, request

I need to set `api_key` as parameter in all requests. You can review the code below. I don't want to write `api_key` in all my request models every time. How can I set this as default? I want the `api_key` in the extension `RequestModelProtocol` to remain `default` in every model.

**Request Model Protocol:**

```
protocol RequestModelProtocol {
    var baseUrl: String { get }
    var parameters: [String: Any] { get }
    var headers: [String: String]? { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var body: [String: Any]? { get }
}

extension RequestModelProtocol {
    var baseUrl: String {
        return MovieDBApiConstant.upcoming.rawValue
    }
    var pararmeters: [String: Any] {
        return ["api_key":"594b8eb499******136ee3ed1ebdb"]
    }
    var headers: [String: String]? {
        return ["accept": "application/json"]
    }
    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }
    var body: [String: Any]? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Upcoming Request Model:**

```
struct UpcomingRequestModel: RequestModelProtocol {
    var baseUrl: String
    var parameters: [String : Any]
    
    init(baseUrl: String, parameters: [String: Any]) {
        self.baseUrl = baseUrl
        self.parameters = parameters
    }
}
```

**Fetch Upcoming Movies:**

```
func fetchUpcomingMovies() {
    dataProvider?.fetchUpcomingMovies(request: .init(baseUrl: MovieDBApiConstant.topRated.rawValue, parameters: ["page": 1, "language": "EN", "api_key":"594b8eb******e3ed1ebdb"]), completion: { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let response):
            print("response: \(response)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("err: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I think it should be done by `dataProvider`

Comment: I don't wanna write again this in request model sir. "api_key":"594b8eb******e3ed1ebdb"

Comment: You shouldn’t hard code the api key at all but if you do then I suggest you use two struct types, one with server specific properties (like the api key) and one with endpoint specific properties. That would make it easier to have default values